# VS Code auto import using require instead of importing ES Module in a React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, frontend, eslint

I'm creating a react project using create-react-app, prettier, ESlint, and Husky. Anytime I create a JS file, it is considered a CommoJS Module instead of an ES Module. And if I try to import any library/package in the js file it is auto imported using "require" not using "import (ES Imports)". I searched across the web but couldn't able to found any solution. I also went through my configuration files whether I accidentally misconfigured any option but everything seems fine.

JavaScript file:

```js
const { default: axios } = require("axios");
// on mouse hover to require it shows the message like
// 'require' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)

// I want this type of auto import
// import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
  // on mouse hover to process it shows the message like
  // var process: NodeJS.Process
  // 'process' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  // Do something before request is sent
  (req) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`;
      return req;
    } else {
      throw { message: "The token is not available" };
    }
  },
  // Do something with request error
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

commitlint.config.js file

```
    module.exports = {
      // on mouse hover to require it shows the message like
      // 'module' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)
      extends: ["@commitlint/config-conventional"],
      rules: {
        "body-leading-blank": [1, "always"],
        "body-max-line-length": [2, "always", 100],
        "footer-leading-blank": [1, "always"],
        "footer-max-line-length": [2, "always", 100],
        "header-max-length": [2, "always", 100],
        "scope-case": [2, "always", "lower-case"],
        "subject-case": [
          2,
          "never",
          [
            "sentence-case",
            "start-case",
            "pascal-case",
            "upper-case",
            "camel-case",
          ],
        ],
        "subject-empty": [2, "never"],
        "subject-full-stop": [2, "never", "."],
        "type-case": [2, "always", "lower-case"],
        "type-empty": [2, "never"],
        "type-enum": [
          2,
          "always",
          [
            "build",
            "chore",
            "ci",
            "docs",
            "feat",
            "fix",
            "perf",
            "refactor",
            "revert",
            "style",
            "test",
            "translation",
            "security",
            "changeset",
            "release",
          ],
        ],
      },
    };
```

My package.json file:
( I tried to add "type": "module" but didn't work)

```
    {
      "name": "highrise",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "license": "ISC",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=16.0.0",
        "yarn": ">=1.22.0",
        "npm": "please-use-yarn"
      },
      "resolutions": {
        "webpack": "^5"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
        "@fontsource/poppins": "^4.5.9",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
        "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.101",
        "@mui/material": "^5.10.6",
        "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.4",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.36.1",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.5.2",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
        "yup": "^0.32.11"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "lint": "eslint --fix",
        "pretty": "prettier --write .",
        "prepare": "husky install"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@commitlint/cli": "^17.1.2",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.1.0",
        "eslint": "^8.23.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1"
      }
    }
```

jsconfig.json file
( I tried adding "module": "es6", but it also didn't work )

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "@public/*": ["public/*"],
          "@src/*": ["src/*"],
          "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
          "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
          "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
          "@store/*": ["src/store/*"],
          "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
        }
      }
    }
```

eslint.json file

```
    {
      "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
      ],
      "globals": {
        "React": "readonly"
      },
      "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": true
        }
      },
      "plugins": ["prettier", "react", "react-hooks"],
      "rules": {
        "no-var": "error",
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
        "no-unused-vars": [
          2,
          {
            "args": "after-used",
            "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
          }
        ],
        "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error", // Checks rules of Hooks
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error" // Checks effect dependencies,
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing a line in jsconfig.json from

```
"compilerOptions": {
/.../
"module": "commonjs",
/.../
}
```

to

```
"compilerOptions": {
/.../
"module": "ES6",
/.../
}
```

Let me know if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall other auto importer for Javascript.
Install this one: [image]

Comment: Thanks Musiur but still facing same issue

Comment: Then you can try to reset the visual studio code and then install all the necessary extensions.

Comment: Tried but still not worked